# Capture Incoming Phone Number with Watson Assistant on integration Voice Over Phone

Tags: twilio, ibm-watson

Hello I am using Watson assistant for voice how can I capture incoming user phone number. I am using Twilio for Integration with Watson assistant.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How have you set up the integration? Can you share any code or config?

Comment: It's all on the cloud no coding.

Comment: How would you like to capture the phone number? Are there logs in the Watson integration? How did you create the integration?

Comment: It's a build in integration i am using SIP trunks for the integration.

Comment: Are you able to view the phone number in IBM log analysis, as described here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-phone#deploy-phone-logs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240029/discussion-between-aymal-and-philnash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$integrations.voice_telephony.private.user_phone_number` context variable to obtain the phone number that the call was received from. For example, you can use this in the welcome node to read back the phone number to the user: `"Hello. You are calling from $integrations.voice_telephony.private.user_phone_number"`